# selenium raises InvalidArgumentException in version 91.0.4472.101 for any given url

Tags: java, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Given:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

def setUp_Browser():
    if 'nt' in os.name.lower():
        # import psutil
        # for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        #     if proc.name() == "chromedriver.exe":
        #         proc.kill()
        time.sleep(1)
        caps = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
        caps['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        options.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')
        options.add_argument("--incognito")
        caps['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True
        import pathlib
        projectDir = str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()) + "\\Resources\\Drivers\\"
        executable_path = os.path.join(projectDir, "chromedriver.exe")
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, options=options, desired_capabilities=caps)
        time.sleep(3)
        self.browser.get(url='www.google.ro')
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(15)
        time.sleep(4)
```

I cannot access any given url, it always raises an invalid arg exception after the latest driver update:

```
  File "C:\Users\MunteanuG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\MunteanuG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\MunteanuG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.101)
```

Some more text so i can post the question...........

Comment: `self.browser.get('www.google.com')`  - try this instead

Comment: Tried it, same outcome

Comment: your chromedriver, chrome broswer, selenium and python version please ?

Comment: it seems that adding https to the url made it work

Answer (score 1):

Adding http or https, and removing "www." from the url seems to work fime